# What causes error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" and how do I solve it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I get stuck with this query:

```sql
SELECT ville_nom, COUNT(*) FROM villes_france_free GROUP BY ville_nom
IN
(
SELECT departement_nom, departement_code, ville_nom FROM departement
INNER JOIN villes_france_free ON departement.departement_code = villes_france_free.ville_departement);
```

The query returns *"operand should contain 1 column(s)"*, and I don't understand why.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: Mysql workbench

Comment: MySQL Workbench is not an RDBMS, it is only a query tool. Your RDBMS is MySQL.

Comment: In any case, `ville_nom IN (SELECT departement_nom, departement_code, ville_nom ...)` won't work: you're comparing a single column to something with three columns.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: Group by does not have IN it has HAVING but WHERE has IN so no idea what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems in your query.
First one, trying to filtering in the group by.
Second, you can't do an IN with multiple columns in your subquery.

Below is the exemple of your query.
Not sure what you are trying to filter but if you are trying to have all the cities from a departement, in France you should adapt your filter.

```
SELECT ville_nom, COUNT(*) FROM villes_france_free 
WHERE ville_nom IN
(
SELECT ville_nom FROM departement
INNER JOIN villes_france_free ON departement.departement_code = villes_france_free.ville_departement)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris ! I'm a beginner, I know I write stupid query... It works ! I used GROUP BY and HAVING instead of IN

Comment: Update : I don't have the whole list with ville_nom. It works when I use ville_departement :) Thanks a lot, you saved my butt